# Generate a stream from another stream result

Tags: dart, stream

I have a stream I want to map the result of that stream to another stream and return the mapped stream.

```
Stream<SomeClass> subscribe() async* {
    final Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> baseStream = api.subscribeToSomething(id: id);

    baseStream.listen(
      (Map<String, dynamic> response) {
        if (response.containsKey('error')) {
          throw Exception(response['error']['message']);
        } else {
          yield SomeClass.fromMap(response['result']);
        }
      },
    );
}
```

but I get this error:

> The method 'yield' isn't defined for the class 'SomeClass'. Try
>   correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a
>   method named 'yield'.

question is how can I map a stream to another stream and return result stream?

Comment: Any reason why you cannot use the `map` method on `Stream`? https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-async/Stream/map.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [julemand101](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1953515/julemand101), the solution is:

```
 Stream<SomeClass> subscribe() => 
    api.subscribeToSomething(id: id).map<SomeClass>(
        (Map<String, dynamic> response) {
          if (response.containsKey('error')) {
            throw Exception(response['error']['message']);
          } else {
            return SomeClass.fromMap(response['result']);
          }
        },
      );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an await-for to listen for events:

```dart
  Stream<SomeClass> subscribe() async* {
    final Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> baseStream = api.subscribeToSomething(id: id);

    await for (var response in baseStream) {
      if (response.containsKey('error')) {
        throw Exception(response['error']['message']);
      } else {
        yield SomeClass.fromMap(response['result']);
      }
    }
  }
```

The `await for` will forward pauses and resumes correctly to the base stream, and it will make errors in the base stream terminate the loop.

(Also, consider creating a subclass of `Exception` for your excepsions, so your users can catch and handle those specifically, rather than having to catch all exceptions).